# How can I create two of TextView like a shadow?

Tags: android

I'm wondering how can I create something like this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihUWm.png), I can do it by creating two of TextView but is there any easier way, or is there an external library?

Comment: IMO two textviews approach is faster  and easier then any library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Android Textview attributes just like shadowDy shadowDx and shadowRadius.I hope it might be helpful for you.

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="12dp"
  android:text="@string/shadow"
  android:textSize="80sp"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:shadowColor="#7000"
  android:shadowDx="12"
  android:shadowDy="12"
  android:shadowRadius="8"/>
```

and You can also check it from this link there are some slides related to textview styles https://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/8